# Button not adjusting well to text that changes dynamically

Tags: android, button

im trying to make a button that it text changes depending what I get from a web service, and for some reason the button doesn't fit to the text very well, I mean the height its more than it should be, I have wrap_content on it but still got a lot of blanc space on the top and on the bottom of the bottom

[image]

```
<ul.ui.FontButton
        android:id="@+id/btnCTA"
        style="@style/button"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Share"
        android:minHeight="1dp"
        android:textColor="@drawable/welcome_button_text"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

that is the code of the button

Comment: what exactly is your question

Comment: try to remove this line android:minHeight="1dp"

Comment: @TimCastelijns how can I make the button with less height to be more fitted to the text

Comment: @JohnKalimeris did that, still have the same problem